# How to fetch all the fields in mongodb aggregate function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have wriiten below lines of code

```
public function BasicSearchStudents($input)
{
    $this->page =1;
    $page=(int)$this->page;
    $skip=($page - 1)*12;
    $param = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
    $arg = trim($param);

    $output= $this->db->studentTbl->aggregate(
          array(
                array(
                        '$project' => array(
                          'fullname' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                          'firstmiddle' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name')),
                          'firstlast' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$last_name')),
                          'first_name' => 1,
                          'middle_name' =>1,
                          'last_name' =>1,
                          'roll_no' =>1,
                          'registration_temp_perm_no' =>1,
                          'email' =>1,
                          'guardian_name' =>1,
                          'phone1' =>1,
                          'phone2' =>1,
                          'dob' =>1,
                          'student_id' =>1,
                          'is_active' =>1,
                          'has_finished' =>1
                      )
                    ),
                 array(
                   '$match' =>
                         array('$or' => 
                            array(
                            array("fullname" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("first_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("middle_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("last_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("firstmiddle" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("firstlast" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("registration_temp_perm_no" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("roll_no" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("email" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("guardian_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("phone1" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                            array("dob" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                    array(
                          'studentresult' => array(
                          '$push' => '$$ROOT'
                          )
                         ), 
                         array('$limit' => 22),
                         array('$skip' =>$skip),
                        )
                     );

           $cursor = $output["studentresult"];
    }
```

I am trying to fetch all the fields used in student collection in by using root after match operation. It throws error "Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message 'localhost:27017: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'result''".
Please help me.

Comment: No one is able to help me in sorting out this problem. It really seems that the forum for mongodb is not well devoleped. Please grow so that developers are not frustrated.

Comment: You already have all the fields in the `$project` stage. Can you explain why are  you `$push`ing the students ? btw the cause of error is you can use `$push` only with `$group` stage. You can add any extra fields you wish to keep by defining them in `$project` stage.